# Metronome for iPhone using Audio Queue

Tags: iphone, audio, queue

I'm trying to develop a metronome for iPhone. I've tried using an NSTimer and Apples SoundEngine.h to play a tick, but it doesn't seem to be very accurate. I've seen several forums that Auido Queue can be used to create a more precise metronome. I haven't used Audio Queue before, but I've looked at "Audio Queue Services Programming Guide" and SpeakHere sample code. Still I don't have a clue as to how to generate sound data on the fly (as opposed to reading from a file) and play it using Audio Queue. Can somebody help me? I'd love to see a code sample or at least some pseudo code describing the steps to do the timing and feed audio data from a short audio clip to the Queues.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

well, you looked at the wrong 'sample code' from apple... see [this one](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Metronome/Introduction/Intro.html)!!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that is a very simple metronome. If you go past 300bpm, some beats can't even be heard. Even my method was better than this implementation. I'm looking for something much more accurate.

Comment: the link is dead. @wingman123 but any chance do you have a copy of it?